# Change header for multiple data frames on global environment

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, apply

I have loaded on my global environment a few data frames (4, all .csv) and I want to eventually `rbind` them all to have them all stacked in one new data frame. As far as I am concerned, I can only `rbind` data frames with the same header, that's why I am trying to change their header to the same name.

I have tried the following:

```
# group all files with the extension .csv 
filenames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")

# then I tried to rename them with a `for loop`
for(i in filenames) {
  names(filenames[i]) <- "epitope"
}
```

It did not work though. I think the trouble is R is not treating the elements in `filename`  (i.e. the four data frames that I have) as independent data.frames per se (whose header should be changed), but rather simply as strings. When I type:

```
filenames[1]
```

I get

```
[1] "abc_65prots_all_15mers.csv"
```

when I was expecting R to ouput my data frame (named abc_65prots_all_15mers.csv).

Comment: use `get(filenames[i])` to refer to the actual object

Comment: `for(i in filenames) {
    names(get(filenames[i])) <- "epitope"
  }`

then I got

`Error in get(`*tmp*`) : object 'NA' not found`

Comment: `i` is not a number, as you might be expecting, but the actual file name. You can try `for (i in 1:length(filenames))`.

Comment: That's indeed a good call, however it did not help unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `get` and `assign` solved the problem

```
# group all files with the extension .csv 
filenames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")

# Then the loop
      for(i in filenames) {
      tables <- get(i)
      names(tables) <- "epitope"
      assign(i, tables)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this untested pseudo code, you could do something like this. `lapply` will take care of the bureaucracy for you.

```
mf <- Sys.glob(".csv")

xy <- lapply(mf, read.table, header = TRUE) # read files into a list

# rename each dataset
xy <- lapply(xy, FUN = function(x) {
  names(x) <- c("vector of names")
})

do.call(rbind, xy) # merge all datasets
```

Comment: `filenames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")`

`xy <- lapply(X = filenames, read.table, header=T)`
`xy <- lapply(xy, FUN = function(x) {
  names(x) <- c("peptides")
})`

`final <- do.call(rbind, xy)`

`final`

`     [,1]      
[1,] "peptides"
[2,] "peptides"
[3,] "peptides"
[4,] "peptides"`

Unfortunately not quite what I want...